# Google Maps API 3 Javascript Adding Polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am building a polygon from an XML sheet. I am getting this error:

Message: Invalid value for constructor parameter 0: (15.850885, -97.058372)

Here is my code:

```
downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) { 
   var xml = parseXml(data);
   var triangleNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("triangle"); 
   for (var i = 0; i < triangleNodes.length; i++) {
   var trianglelatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(triangleNodes[i].getAttribute("triangle_lat")),
          parseFloat(triangleNodes[i].getAttribute("triangle_lng")),
          parseFloat(triangleNodes[i].getAttribute("triangle_lat1")),
          parseFloat(triangleNodes[i].getAttribute("triangle_lng1")),
          parseFloat(triangleNodes[i].getAttribute("triangle_lat2")), 
          parseFloat(triangleNodes[i].getAttribute("triangle_lng2")),
          parseFloat(triangleNodes[i].getAttribute("triangle_lat")),
          parseFloat(triangleNodes[i].getAttribute("triangle_lng")));
          createTriangle(trianglelatlng);
          }
```

As you can see here I am constructing my polygon array.

Now I am attempting to add the polygon to my map:

```
function createTriangle(trianglelatlng) { 
  var html2 = "<div id='infodiv'>HelloMatt</div>"; 
    var triangle = new google.maps.Polygon({     
        paths: trianglelatlng,     
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",     
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,    
        strokeWeight: 2,
        zIndex: 7,     
        fillColor: "#FF0000",     
        fillOpacity: 0.35
        });

triangle.setMap(map);
```

However if I add a static array such as below the polygon will show on the map.

```
var triangleCoords = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
  new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
  new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
  new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
  ];
```

I have also declared the var triangle in the global variables. 
I am certain the issue is in the way I am constructing my array. Hopefully someone has constructed a polygon and can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in the first case your var triangleCoords is created only as a `LatLng` element (see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)) while you need an array of LatLng, that you correctly make in the second way you describe. Try to add each point in the for loop to a pre-defined array and use that.

Hope it helps